# Snmp code gives me this error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/snmp4j/TransportMapping

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j, snmpd

i have been trying to apply commands of snmp at java on Ubuntu, i find  an example code at stackoverflow and code's github link: https://github.com/jineshmathewt/snmpbulkwalk/blob/master/snmpbulkwalk/src/TestSNMP.java
But when i try to execute i m getting an error .

[image: But when i try to execute i m getting an error .]

i would like to ask what am i doing wrong ? , to mention i can use get command on terminal and it works .

public class TestSNMP {

```
private static final String SNMPPORT = "161";
private static final int snmpVersion = SnmpConstants.version2c;
private int snmpTimeout = 500;
private int numRetries = 2;

public void doSNMPBulkWalk(String ipAddr, String commStr, String bulkOID, String operation) throws IOException {

    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
    UserTarget targetV3 = null;
    CommunityTarget targetV2 = null;
    UsmUser user = null;
    PDU request = null;
    snmp.listen();
    Address add = new UdpAddress(ipAddr + "/" + SNMPPORT);

    if (snmpVersion == SnmpConstants.version2c || snmpVersion == SnmpConstants.version1) {
        targetV2 = new CommunityTarget();
        targetV2.setCommunity(new OctetString(commStr));
        targetV2.setAddress(add);
        targetV2.setTimeout(snmpTimeout);
        targetV2.setRetries(numRetries);
        targetV2.setVersion(snmpVersion);
        targetV2.setMaxSizeRequestPDU(65535);
    }

    if (snmpVersion == SnmpConstants.version2c) {
        request = new PDU();
        //request.setMaxRepetitions(100);
        //request.setNonRepeaters(0);
    }

    request.setType(PDU.GETBULK);
    OID oID = new OID(bulkOID);
    request.add(new VariableBinding(oID));
    OID rootOID = request.get(0).getOid();
    VariableBinding vb, ar[];
    List<TreeEvent> l = null;
    TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, new DefaultPDUFactory());
    if (snmpVersion == SnmpConstants.version2c) {
        targetV2.setCommunity(new OctetString(commStr));
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("bulkwalk")) {
            OID[] rootOIDs = new OID[1];
            rootOIDs[0] = rootOID;
            l = treeUtils.walk(targetV2, rootOIDs);
        } else {
            l = treeUtils.getSubtree(targetV2, rootOID);
        }

    }
    //System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println("size="+l.size());
    for(TreeEvent t : l){
        VariableBinding[] vbs= t.getVariableBindings();
        for (int i = 0; (vbs != null) && i < vbs.length; i++) {
            vb = vbs[i];
            String s = vb.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Date d1 = new Date();
    TestSNMP snmpTest = new TestSNMP();
    try {
        snmpTest.doSNMPBulkWalk(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date d2 = new Date();
    System.out.println("Time Elapsed=" + (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()));

}
```

}

Comment: are you running it from an IDE or CLI ? where did you put the lib containing the package org.snmp4j ?

Comment: Trying to work it on eclipse ide and i didnt create lib

Answer (score 0):

I think the snmp library jar is not included in the eclipse project. You have to download the snmp library jar from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.snmp4j). Right click on the project and go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and add those library jar there using Add External Jars.

Comment: But  , if you can just look my screenshot , i added